# SFDataGrid pagination with SFDataPager not working

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable, pagination, syncfusion

I am a beginner in flutter mobile development. I am currently using a Package in flutter called syncfusion_flutter_datagrid, I am having a problem where the SFDataPager, which is used for pagination, is not working and the SFDataGrid is still scrolling and not divided into pages, although the pageCount is working and does have 2 pages (I currently have 15 items for the data table) because it only does calculations, but the rowsPerPages is not working because the data table still has 15 items and is still scrollable. I do not know if there is anything missing in my code especially in the DataGridSource class because both the SFDataGrid and SFDataPager is connected to the DataGridSource.

Here is my widgets in the view class:

```
              AppDataGrid(
                dtrHistoryData: _controller.historyData.value,
                columns: _controller.columns,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: dataPagerHeight,
                width: double.maxFinite,
                // color: Colors.white,
                child: Center(
                  child: SfDataPager(
                    pageCount: ((_controller.historyData.value.timeData
                                    ?.length ??
                                1) /
                            10)
                        .ceilToDouble(),
                    delegate: DTRHistoryDataGridSource(
                        dtrHistoryData: _controller.historyData.value),
                    direction: Axis.horizontal,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

This is the SFDataGrid (AppDataGrid):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:puncher_app/app/global/constants/colors.dart';
import 'package:puncher_app/app/models/dtr_history_data.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_core/theme.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid/datagrid.dart';

import '../../data/table/history_table2_data.dart';

class AppDataGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  final DTRHistoryData dtrHistoryData;
  final List<GridColumn> columns;

  const AppDataGrid({
    super.key,
    required this.dtrHistoryData,
    required this.columns,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Card(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
        color: transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        child: SfDataGridTheme(
          data: SfDataGridThemeData(
            headerColor: secondaryColor,
          ),
          child: SfDataGrid(
            rowsPerPage: 11,
            verticalScrollPhysics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            horizontalScrollPhysics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            headerGridLinesVisibility: GridLinesVisibility.none,
            gridLinesVisibility: GridLinesVisibility.horizontal,
            source: DTRHistoryDataGridSource(
              dtrHistoryData: dtrHistoryData,
            ),
            columns: columns,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the DataGridSource:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:puncher_app/app/global/constants/colors.dart';
import 'package:puncher_app/app/global/constants/styles.dart';
import 'package:puncher_app/app/global/widgets/app_text.dart';
import 'package:puncher_app/app/models/dtr_history_data.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid/datagrid.dart';

class DTRHistoryDataGridSource extends DataGridSource {
  late List<DataGridRow> _dtrHistoryDataGridRows;
  late DTRHistoryData _dtrHistoryData = DTRHistoryData();

  DTRHistoryDataGridSource({required DTRHistoryData dtrHistoryData}) {
    _dtrHistoryData = dtrHistoryData;
    buildDataGridRows();
  }

  void buildDataGridRows() {
    final dateFormat = DateFormat('hh:mm a');
    _dtrHistoryDataGridRows = _dtrHistoryData.timeData
            ?.map<DataGridRow>(
              (timeData) => DataGridRow(
                cells: [
                  DataGridCell<String>(
                    columnName: 'Date',
                    value: timeData.date,
                  ),
                  DataGridCell<String>(
                    columnName: 'Time In',
                    value: timeData.timeIn?.isNotEmpty == true
                        ? dateFormat.format(
                            DateTime.parse(timeData.timeIn!),
                          )
                        : '--',
                  ),
                  DataGridCell<String>(
                    columnName: 'Time Out',
                    value: timeData.timeOut?.isNotEmpty == true
                        ? dateFormat.format(
                            DateTime.parse(timeData.timeOut!),
                          )
                        : '--',
                  ),
                  DataGridCell<String>(
                    columnName: 'Duration',
                    value: timeData.duration != null
                        ? formatDuration(timeData.duration!)
                        : '--',
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
            .toList() ??
        [];
  }

  String formatDuration(String duration) {
    final parts = duration.split(' ');
    final hours = parts[0];
    final minutes = parts[2];

    return '${hours}h${minutes}m';
  }

  @override
  List<DataGridRow> get rows => _dtrHistoryDataGridRows;

  @override
  DataGridRowAdapter buildRow(DataGridRow row) {
    return DataGridRowAdapter(
        cells: row.getCells().map<Widget>((dataGridCell) {
      return Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: AppText(
            text: dataGridCell.value.toString(),
            textColor: secondaryColor,
            style: kRegTextBlack,
            alignment: TextAlign.center,
          ));
    }).toList());
  }

  @override
  Object getValue(int rowIndex, String columnName) {
    final TimeData timeData = _dtrHistoryData.timeData![rowIndex];
    switch (columnName) {
      case 'Date':
        return timeData.date!;
      case 'Time In':
        return timeData.timeIn!;
      case 'Time Out':
        return timeData.timeOut!;
      case 'Duration':
        return timeData.duration!;
      default:
        return '';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure proper functionality of the DataGrid and DataPager components, it's important to avoid creating the **SfDataGrid.source** and **SfDataPager.delegate** separately. Instead, please create an instance for the DTRHistoryDataGridSource and assign it to both SfDataGrid.source and SfDataPager.delegate properties. I have attached a code snippet and sample below that demonstrates this approach for your convenience.

Code snippet:

```dart
  late EmployeeDataSource _employeeDataSource;
  List<Employee> _employees = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _employees = populateData();
    _employeeDataSource = EmployeeDataSource(employees: _employees);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Demo Sample'),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                  height: constraints.maxHeight - 60,
                  width: constraints.maxWidth,
                  child: SfDataGrid(
                      rowsPerPage: 11,
                      source: _employeeDataSource,
                      columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.fill,
                      columns: getColumns)),
              SizedBox(
                height: 60,
                width: constraints.maxWidth,
                child: SfDataPager(
                  pageCount: (_employees.length / 10).ceilToDouble(),
                  delegate: _employeeDataSource,
                  direction: Axis.horizontal,
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Sample:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid/datagrid.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Syncfusion DataGrid Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

List<Employee> paginatedDataSource = [];

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late EmployeeDataSource _employeeDataSource;
  List<Employee> _employees = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _employees = populateData();
    _employeeDataSource = EmployeeDataSource(employees: _employees);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Demo Sample'),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                  height: constraints.maxHeight - 60,
                  width: constraints.maxWidth,
                  child: SfDataGrid(
                      rowsPerPage: 11,
                      source: _employeeDataSource,
                      columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.fill,
                      columns: getColumns)),
              SizedBox(
                height: 60,
                width: constraints.maxWidth,
                child: SfDataPager(
                  pageCount: (_employees.length / 10).ceilToDouble(),
                  delegate: _employeeDataSource,
                  direction: Axis.horizontal,
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  List<GridColumn> get getColumns {
    return <GridColumn>[
      GridColumn(
          columnName: 'id',
          label: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text(
                'ID',
              ))),
      GridColumn(
          columnName: 'name',
          label: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text('Name'))),
      GridColumn(
          columnName: 'designation',
          width: 110,
          label: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text(
                'Designation',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ))),
      GridColumn(
          columnName: 'salary',
          label: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Text('Salary'))),
    ];
  }
}

List<Employee> populateData() {
  return [
    Employee(10001, 'Jack', 'Manager', 150000),
    Employee(10002, 'Perry', 'Project Lead', 80000),
    Employee(10003, 'James', 'Developer', 55000),
    Employee(10004, 'Michael', 'Designer', 39000),
    Employee(10005, 'Roland Mendel', 'Developer', 45000),
    Employee(10006, 'Sven', 'UI Designer', 36000),
    Employee(10007, 'Williams', 'Developer', 44000),
    Employee(10008, 'Adams', 'Developer', 43000),
    Employee(10009, 'Edwards', 'QA Testing', 43000),
    Employee(10010, 'Grimes', 'Developer', 43000),
    Employee(10011, 'Maria Andres', 'Developer', 41000),
    Employee(10012, 'Thomas Hardy', 'Developer', 40000),
    Employee(10013, 'Hanna Moos', 'Sales Associate', 350000),
    Employee(10014, 'Elizabeth', 'Developer', 41000),
    Employee(10015, 'Patrick Simpson', 'Administrator', 33000)
  ];
}

class EmployeeDataSource extends DataGridSource {
  EmployeeDataSource({required List<Employee> employees}) {
    buildDataGridRows(employees);
  }

  List<DataGridRow> _employeeData = [];

  @override
  List<DataGridRow> get rows => _employeeData;

  void buildDataGridRows(List<Employee> employees) {
    _employeeData = employees
        .map<DataGridRow>((e) => DataGridRow(cells: [
              DataGridCell<int>(columnName: 'id', value: e.id),
              DataGridCell<String>(columnName: 'name', value: e.name),
              DataGridCell<String>(
                  columnName: 'designation', value: e.designation),
              DataGridCell<int>(columnName: 'salary', value: e.salary),
            ]))
        .toList();
  }

  @override
  DataGridRowAdapter buildRow(DataGridRow row) {
    return DataGridRowAdapter(
        cells: row.getCells().map<Widget>((e) {
      return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: Text(e.value.toString()),
      );
    }).toList());
  }
}

class Employee {
  Employee(this.id, this.name, this.designation, this.salary);

  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String designation;
  final int salary;
}
```